# How to store spesific item of JSON file to new JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have JSON file that have several items. And I want to get item 'desc' and store them into new JSON file. Can you help to solve it? Because I am newbie in Python. Thank you.

```
[
    {"title": "Indonesia Darurat Matematika!", "url": "https://edukasi.kompas.com/read/2018/09/24/07200071/indonesia-darurat-matematika", "tag": ["Matematika", "pelajaran"], "author": "Ahmad Rizali", "date": "Kompas.com - 24/09/2018, 07:20 WIB", "desc": ["KOMPAS.com", " \u2014 Entah apa yang sudah dilakukan oleh Kementerian Pendidikan dan Kebudayaan (Kemendikbud), dinas pendidikan provinsi dan kabupaten kota dalam menyikapi fakta rendahnya keterampilan berhitung warga sekolah yang dikelolanya, selain mengucurkan Tunjangan Profesi Pendidik (TPP) yang tahun ini berjumlah lebih dari Rp 71 triliun di APBN, yang tak berdampak berarti kepada kenaikan kompetensi guru (De Ree dkk, WB 2016).", "Apalagi, ketika keterampilan itu dijadikan tolok ukur kesiapan menghadapi era abad ke-21 dan sebuah studi terbaru (Amanda dkk, CFEE Annual Digest 2018) yang menyatakan bahwa anak muda Indonesia akan siap menghadapi abad ke-21, ketika abad ke-31 menjelang, karena studi tersebut menghitung bahwa selama sekian tahun sejak masuk SD hingga lulus SMA sekolah hanya meningkatkan keterampilan menghitung atau aritmatika sederhana dari peserta didik sebanyak nol koma nol sekian persen.", "Hasil studi makro tersebut sejalan dengan hasil ulangan di sebuah kelas di SMA di Kalimantan Tengah yang diunggah oleh seorang guru (Rukim, 2018) pada awal September 2018. Ketika hasil studi itu didiskusikan dengan koleganya di pulau dan kota lain, hasilnya tak jauh berbeda.", "Kesimpulannya, meski duduk di kelas IPA, murid tak terampil menyelesaikan operasi sederhana \"tambah, kurang, kali dan bagi\" termasuk pengertian \"peratus atau prosen\", perpuluhan dan pecahan. Padahal, sebuah operasi paling dasar dari aritmatika, seperti menyambung huruf membentuk kata dan kalimat \"i-ni bu-di...\" dalam konteks membaca dan menulis.", "Satu catatan penting, yakni delapan tahun lalu, sudah diingatkan bahwa keadaan darurat buta  ", "matematika", " ini (Koran Tempo, 2008) dengan merujuk ke hasil uji PISA (Program for International Student Assesement) dan uji TIMSS (Trend for International Mathematic and Sciences Study) ketika peringkat siswa Indonesia kelas 2 SMP/MTs hanya selapis di atas Bostwana Afrika.", "Ya, peringkat Indonesia nomor dua dari bawah! Sebuah kondisi buta total matematika, dan mereka diramalkan tak siap menghadapi abad ke-21.", "Tulisan tersebut yang sudah pasti hanya sebuah peringatan kecil keadaan darurat, karena cukup banyak tulisan lain yang mengingatkan situasi serupa. Tapi, hal itu ternyata dianggap sepi oleh pemerintah yang menganggap semuanya baik-baik saja.", "Gerakan transformasi eksponensial", "Sikap \"Complacency\" yang menganggap sebuah persoalan darurat seperti angin lalu adalah sebuah pembiaran dan merupakan kejahatan publik berdosa besar. Persis seperti membiarkan seorang yang diketahui merokok sambil mengisi bensin atau membiarkan got lingkungan rumah tinggalnya penuh jentik nyamuk DBD.", "Mirisnya, sulit berharap insiatif perbaikan tersebut datang dari pemerintah, apalagi jika mengikuti logika ", "paper", " itu, bahwa baku mutu yang memenuhi syarat baru siap di abad ke-31.", "Untuk itu, perubahan perbaikan keterampilan tersebut haruslah dimulai secara linier dengan sudut yang curam dan segera menjadi deret ukur atau eksponensial. Insiatif harus dimulai dari organisasi masyarakat sipil (civil society organisation) dan bersama sama membuat sebuah platform untuk berbagi peran.", "Tidak sulit mengurainya, terutama jika kita mulai dengan menelaah beberapa Standar Nasional Pendidikan (SNP), yaitu Standar Kompetensi Lulusan (SKL), Standar Isi (SI) dan Standar Proses (SP) untuk Matpel  ", "Matematika", " SD hingga SMP.", "Begitu sudah diketahui \"bottle-neck\" dari telaah itu, kita ajak relawan yang faham operasi aritmatika dasar, yang dengan metodenya bisa saling memeriksa keterampilan putra-putrinya mulai SD sampai SMP dan mencari persoalan yang menghambat serapan mereka atas mata  ", "pelajaran", " tersebut.", "Karena disebut matematika dasar seharusnya itu tidak rumit, karena terjadi kasat mata dalam kehidupan keseharian kita. Belanja ke pasar atau minimarket, kredit motor, membeli bakso, membayar zakat, menghitung hutang harian ke bank pasar, bahkan berbagi warisan peninggalan orang tua, semua memerlukan keterampilan dasar berhitung.", "Maka, mereka yang sudah lulus SMA, meskipun mungkin lupa, pasti akan mudah mengingat kembali, apalagi mereka yang lulus di bidang Rekayasa dan MIPA seharusnya masih terampil.", "Gerakan ini sulit dan akan menjadi masif, bahkan terukur jika tak dirancang dengan baik. Untuk itu, setiap pemangku kepentingan harus dipetakan perannya, termasuk yang hanya mampu menyumbang uang, bukan keterampilan.", "Uang sangat berarti, tapi sebuah gerakan lebih memerlukan semangat berbagi apa yang dimiliki dan tentu kesadaran kondisi darurat, baik dari si penerima manfaat (guru dan murid) atau pemangku kepentingan lain.", "Hal tersulit dalam menggelindingkan gerakan ini menjadi bola salju adalah meyakinkan semua pemangku kepentingan, terutama orangtua murid (Sumintono, 2017) bahwa kondisi sudah darurat nasional, karena sikap \"complacency\" itu sangat sulit berubah, dan sama sulitnya meyakinkan akan adanya banjir bandang jika hutan di ketinggian tidak dijaga, kecuali langsung mengalami sendiri.", "Tetapi, pertanyaannya, akankah kita menunggu datangnya abad ke-31 barulah di liang kubur kita berteriak, siapkah akhirnya cucu dan cicit kita menghadapi abad-21?"]},
    {"title": "Anak-Anak Gampang \"Penyok\"", "url": "https://edukasi.kompas.com/read/2018/10/18/22410681/anak-anak-gampang-penyok", "tag": ["korban gempa", "pengungsi", "anak", "Kak Seto", "korban bencana"], "author": "Yohanes Enggar Harususilo", "date": "Kompas.com - 18/10/2018, 22:41 WIB", "desc": ["KOMPAS.com", " -  ", "Anak", " ibarat patung lilin masih lentur sekali yang kalau jatuh gampang \"penyok-penyok\". Kalau tidak segera diperbaiki, maka  ", "anak", " akan \"penyok\" terus. Demikian perumpamaan disampaikan psikolog dan pemerhati anak, Seto Mulyadi.", "Hal itu diutarakan psikolog yang akrab dipanggil  ", "Kak Seto", " itu mengenai upaya menangani anak-anak  ", "korban bencana", " alam. Menurut Kak Seto, anak-anak korban bencana jangan terlambat ditangani dan harus diperhatikan secepatnya karena mereka yang paling terguncang jiwanya.", "\u201cMereka harus dikembalikan pada dunianya yaitu dunia bermain. Bangkitkan kembali semangat mereka \u00a0agar membuat mereka tahan banting, berani menghadapi kenyataan dan segera beradaptasi di lingkungan yang baru,\" kata pencipta boneka Si Komo di Jakarta, (17/10/2018) dalam peluncuran Gerakan SENSASI atau\u00a0", "Sejuta Anak Indonesia Terproteksi\u00a0", "yang digagas Dompet Dhuafa.", "Dikutip dari laman forum Sahabat Keluarga Kemendikbud, upaya membawa anak-anak korban bencana agar kembali ke dunia bermain itu, menurutnya, juga harus dilakukan dengan cara bermain, bernyanyi, melompat-lompat, baca puisi, mencipta lagu, dan mendongeng.", "Baca juga: ", "Karena itu, siapapun yang jadi sukarelawan atau pendamping anak-anak korban bencana, harus kreatif, baik melalui lagu-lagu, puisi, menari, mendongeng, main sulap dan sebagainya.", "Seiring dengan upaya itu, para orangtuanya juga perlu dilatih dan dididik untuk lebih tenang, lebih sabar dan kreatif.", "\u201cItu sebenarnya bukan hanya untuk orangtua tapi untuk seluruh orang dewasa yang ada di pengungsian sebagai upaya pemenuhan hak anak,\" kata Ketua Lembaga Perlindungan Anak Indonesia (LPAI) yang selalu terjun langsung menangangi anak-anak korban bencana alam sejak di Aceh, Nias, Yogyakarta, Lombok dan sekarang di Sulawesi Tengah.", "Ditegaskan Kak Seto, upaya melindungi anak agar aman dan nyaman itu perlu orang sekampung. Hal itu mengingat ada banyak anak yang juga kehilangan keluarganya. \u201cNah, pada anak itu, tetangga kiri dan kanan, dan orang-orang di sekitarnya wajib mengayomi, dan melindungi anak-anak tersebut agar pulih dan kembali ceria,\" paparnya.", "Apalagi, Kak Seto mengingatkan, dalam kondisi di pengungsian yang serba tidak pasti dan tidak teratur itu, rentan terjadi tindak penculikan, kekerasan, eksploitasi seks dan perdagangan anak.", "Diakuinya, proses pemulihan kondisi kejiwaan anak itu tergantung juga pada tipe kepribadian si anak yang artinya tergantung pada pola asuh yang diterapkan orangtuanya.", "\u201cJuga tak bisa kita abaikan faktor bawaan, ada yang mudah frustrasi, atau sebaliknya tahan banting. Juga tergantung pada pengalaman mereka saat bencana itu terjadi, tentunya anak yang mengalami terseret tsunami atau tertimpa bangunan akan beda kondisi kejiwaannya dengan anak yang tidak mengalaminya, yang terakhir, tergantung pada treatment psikologis yang diterapkan,\" jelas pria kelahiran tahun 1951 itu.", "Semua proses pemulihan jiwa anak itu, diketakan Kak Seto, mengacu pada apa yang namanya belajar sosial. Maksudnya, si anak bisa melihat teman-teman di sekelilingnya yang sama-sama senasib.", "Jadi, diantara anak-anak senasib itu saling belajar dan saling memberikan dukungan. \u201cItu sebenarnya yang kami terapkan melalui terapi bermain, bernyanyi, mendongeng, dan lain-lainnya itu,\" katanya.", "Kak Seto juga mengingatkan media untuk tidak sembarangan bertanya pada si anak tentang pengalamannya di saat bencana datang. Bila si anak kondisi kejiwaannya belum pulih, mengenang pengalamannya di saat bencana datang akan membuat kondisi kejiwaannya sulit untuk pulih.", "Kak Seto meminta pemerintah membentuk tim kordinator para relawan agar saling berkoordinasi menangani anak korban bencana. Hal itu diperlukan agar para sukarelawan yang datang dari berbagai organisasi yang berbeda itu membawa teori masing-masing yang mungkin sebetulnya tidak cocok dengan kondisi sosial di daerah bencana itu.", "\u201cPerlu ada panduan yang diterbitkan pemerintah,\" tegasnya."]},
    {"title": "ISI Yogyakarta Bangun Jiwa Pemenang lewat \"Peksiminas 2018\"", "url": "https://edukasi.kompas.com/read/2018/10/17/19580801/isi-yogyakarta-bangun-jiwa-pemenang-lewat-peksiminas-2018", "tag": ["seni", "ISI Yogyakarta", "budaya"], "author": "Yohanes Enggar Harususilo", "date": "Kompas.com - 17/10/2018, 19:58 WIB", "desc": ["KOMPAS.com - ", "Dalam rangka menanamkan nilai-nilai karakter bangsa bagi mahasiswa melalui  ", "seni", " dan  ", "budaya", ", Direktorat Jenderal Pembelajaran dan Kemahasiswaan Kemenristekdikti menggelar Pekan  ", "Seni", " Mahasiswa Nasional (Peksiminas) dilaksanakan tanggal 15-21 Oktober 2018 di Institut Seni Indonesia (ISI) Yogyakarta.", "Acara pembukaan Peksiminas yang dilaksanakan di lapangan Pancasila Universitas Gadjah Mada (UGM) dihadiri Direktur Kemahasiswaan Didin Wahidin, Rektor  ", "ISI Yogyakarta", " Agus Burhan, Rektor UGM Panut Mulyono dan Badan Pembina Seni Mahasiswa Indonesia (BPSMI) Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta.", "Direktur Kemahasiswaan dalam sambutannya menyampaikan bahwa dalam mengikuti kompetisi ini mahasiswa bukan hanya mendapatkan hadiah keluar sebagai pemenang namun banyak hal lain yang bisa mahasiswa dapatkan.", "Baca juga: ", "\u00a0", "\u201cDalam sebuah kompetisi menang itu penting, namun yang lebih penting adalah terbangunnya jiwa pemenang, yaitu berupa semangat juang yang kuat dan tidak kenal menyerah, sportivitas dan kerja tim\u201d ujar Didin seperti dikutip dari laman resmi Kemenristekdikti.", "Penyelenggaraan Peksiminas digelar 2 tahun sekali dan tahun 2018 ini merupakan Peksiminas XIV dimana pesertanya adalah mahasiswa terbaik yang lolos dalam Pekan Seni Mahasiswa Daerah (Peksimida).", "Pelaksaan Peksiminas tahun 2018 ini diikuti 33 pengda BPSMI dengan sejumlah 1.036 mahasiswa dan 441 official. Ada 8 (delapan) perguruan tinggi yang mengirimkan mahasiswanya untuk mengikutin PEKSIMINAS, diantaranya :", "1. ISI Jogjakarta", "2. Universitas Gadjah Mada", "3. Universitas Ahmad Dahlan", "4. Universitas Sanata Dharma", "5. STIKOM AKINDO Jogjakarta", "6. Universitas Kristen Duta Wacana Jogjakarta", "7. Sekolah Tinggi Pembangunan Masyarakat Desa \u2013 APMD", "8. Universitas Katolik Atma Jaya Jogjakarta", "Sebanyak 15 rangkaian lomba diikuti peserta Peksiminas di antaranya: vokal grup, pop, dangdut, keroncong, seriosa, tari, baca puisi, monolog, penulisan puisi, penulisan cerpen, penulisan lakon, desain poster, lukis, fotografi dan komik strip.", "Penyelenggaraan PEKSIMINAS digelar dua tahun sekali dan untuk tahun 2018 ini merupakan PEKSIMINAS XIV dimana pesertanya adalah mahasiswa terbaik yang lolos dalam Pekan Seni Mahasiswa Daerah (PEKSIMIDA). Pelaksaan PEKSIMINAS ke XIV tahun 2018 diikuti oleh 33 pengda BPSMI dengan sejumlah 1.036 mahasiswa dan 441 official. Ada 8 (delapan) perguruan tinggi yang mengirimkan mahasiswanya untuk mengikutin PEKSIMINAS, diantaranya :", "1. ISI Jogjakarta;", "2. Universitas Gadjah Mada;", "3. Universitas Ahmad Dahlan;", "4. Universitas Sanata Dharma;", "5. STIKOM AKINDO Jogjakarta;", "6. Universitas Kristen Duta Wacana Jogjakarta;", "7. Sekolah Tinggi Pembangunan Masyarakat Desa \u2013 APMD;", "8. Universitas Katolik Atma Jaya Jogjakarta."]}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a list of dicts so you can just do a list comprehension.

```
[x["desc"] for x in json_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
import json

# open and load data in your first json file
with open('d.json') as data:
    data = json.load(data)

# create a new json file, loop over the data, and take only desc, write it to the new json file d2
with open('d2.json', 'w') as data2:
    for i in data:
        json.dump(i['desc'], data2)
```